Error loading data: while parsing a block mapping did not find epected key
Trying to deploy to Platform.sh, created a project and then pushed it, and got this error:
E: Error parsing configuration files:
      - applications./.platform.app.yaml: Error loading data: while parsing a block mapping
            in "/.platform.app.yaml", line 12, column 5
          did not find expected key
            in "/.platform.app.yaml", line 13, column 7
  To git.us-3.platform.sh:wahnombqmn2eg.git
   ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> main (invalid configuration files)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'git.us-3.platform.sh:wahnombqmn2eg.git'

What I've tried and they all don't work...

Google search and reading up on what the error might be
ChatGPT recommendations
Stack Overflow recommendations (same as ChatGPT)
Using YAML lint to reformat
Copy pasting original files from the Python Crash Course book (.platform and .platform.app.yaml file) in the projects folder, creating a new project, and then pushing the changes

Original YAML code:
name: "ll_project"
type: "python:3.12"

relationships:
  database: "db:postgresql"

# The configuration of the app when it's exposed to the web
web:
  upstream:
    socket_family: unix
  commands:
    start: "gunicorn -w 4 -b unix:$SOCKET ll_project.wsgi:application"
  locations:
    "/":
      passthru: true
    "/static":
      root: "static"
      expires: "1h"
      allow: true

# The size of the persistent disk of the application (in MB)
disk: 512

# Set a local read/write mount for logs
mounts:
  logs:
    source: "local"
    source_path: "logs"

# The hooks executed at various points in the lifecycle of the application
hooks:
  build: |
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    pip install -r requirements_remote.txt

    mkdir -p logs
    python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
  deploy: |
    python manage.py migrate --noinput


Not sure if this causes the error but the exact start command in the course text (https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/deploying_django/deploying_to_platformsh/) is: gunicorn -w 4 -b unix:$SOCKET learning_log.wsgi:application (not ... ll_project.wsgi:application)

Are lines 12 and 13 in your actual file the 12th and 13th lines here? I can't make sense of the error message based on the quote here and I wonder if you might have a blank line difference changing the line count.

I copied the contents of your yaml file above and pasted it into a new python project on platform.sh and it worked as expected. Are you sure you don't have any other unusual whitespace characters in the file that might cause an issue?
Also, the cli tool itself can help you validate the configuration file. While in the project directory, you can run platform validate which will parse the config file and let you know if there are issues.
